# How to add Select Option type sub menu to firefox when we do right click?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to write a simple firefox addon which display a few options when we do right click. In those few option, i want a select option instead of just a label. I want something like *Execute profile* in the image. Currently,I have only found a way to create label but could not find a way to create select option sub menu at all. Here is What i found:

```
browser.menus.create({
  id: "radio-green",
  type: "radio",
  title: "Make it green",
  contexts: ["all"],
  checked: false
}, onCreated);
```

Here what i want:

[image: sample of multiple option]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assign `ID` to the parent and setting `parentId` to the child submenu, those appear as submenu of the parent menu.

ref: [menus.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/create)

Example:

```
browser.menus.create({
  id: "radio-green",
  type: "radio",
  title: "Make it green",
  contexts: ["all"],
  checked: false
}, onCreated);


// submenu
browser.menus.create({
  id: "sub1",
  parentId: "radio-green",
  type: "radio",
  title: "Submenu",
  contexts: ["all"],
  checked: false
}, onCreated);
```